How to Create Rectangular Segments from a Given Line Segment in a 3D Cartesian Space?
I apologize for my ignorance, but I am still in middle school and we have not yet covered topics like this in school, which seems to me related to ?linear algebra?.
I am writing a renderer for OSM maps in JavaScript using THREE.js, and long story short, I need to convert a segment into a rectangle. In my code, I represent a segment with 2 points in a three-dimensional Cartesian space, even though the y dimension is negligible, so the calculations I perform are on x and z: seg1 = [x1, x2, z1, z2]. Now, from this segment represented by 2 points, I would like to create 2 more segments, meaning 4 new points in total. These 2 segments must be of the same length as the original one but shifted above and below it. Unfortunately, I lack the necessary vocabulary to explain my question better, so I'm leaving a diagram below that explains what I mean ;drawing
I thank anyone in advance for any suggestions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The rectangle isn't fully defined by the segment since many planes will pass through the line segment. You'll need more information to make a rectangle without ambiguity.

What you have drawn is a segment in the xy-plane. You know how long your segment must be on each end; call it $l$. Initially, imagine drawing each end segment horizontally with the mid-point through the end point. The angle of the midline wrt the horizontal is $\theta = tan^{-1}(m)$ where $m$ is the slope of the midline. The end segments must each be rotated $\rho = \theta+\pi/2$ and their new end points will be $(x_e + l\cos(\rho)/2, y_e + l\sin(\rho)/2$ and $(x_e + l\cos(\rho+\pi)/2, y_e + l\sin(\rho+\pi)/2$ where $(x_e,y_e)$ are the coordinates at an end of the midline. Here is a demonstration using SymPy:
m1,m2 = (Point(1,3),Point(4,5))
l=1
dm = m2-m1
m=dm.y/dm.y
theta=atan(m)
rho=theta+pi/2
for xe,ye in (m1,m2):
    print(Point(xe+l*cos(rho)/2,ye+l*sin(rho)/2).n(4))
    print(Point(xe+l*cos(rho+pi)/2,ye+l*sin(rho+pi)/2).n(4))

That code prints the end points of the end-segments which would be the vertices of the rectangle that you are seeking, in the xy-plane.
Point2D(0.6464, 3.354)
Point2D(1.354, 2.646)
Point2D(3.646, 5.354)
Point2D(4.354, 4.646)

If you consider lines in 3 dimensions, you will still be viewing them in a plane, but there are lots of other details to consider. But maybe this is enough to get you going.

Thank you very much, you answered my question completely!
